# Why does SetGravity onToast have no effect?

Tags: android

I have an activity that tries to create a custom toast object. I would like the toast to show up in the center of the screen however no matter what I set the gravity to be, the toast shows up at the very top. It looks like the settings I give the toast have no effect on what happens. What can I do to move the toast to the center.

The code to create the toast:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
                            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_layout,null);

((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(title);
((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.content)).setText(content);
Toast toast = new Toast(this);

toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

The xml that the layout is inflating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/notificationToast">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="content"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the layout your toast is inflating in is only 100dp. The CENTER variable puts the toast in the center of its parent layout. Make the height of the parent layout the the entire screen (match_parent). Then when you call setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0) it will be in the center of the screen aka center of the parent layout.

Toast: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html
Gravity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html

Comment: Stupid little mistakes always take the longest to find. Thank you

Comment: Happens to the best of us